# Take only the first few seconds of an wav file (returned by WATSON of IBM) in PHP

Tags: php, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I am currently using Watson text-to-speech of IBM using PHP. It works well but I have found that the audio has a duration of 27 hours (whereas watson speaks only a few seconds).

When I opened the .wav I have found that it automatically stops when the voice stops (thus after a few seconds). Thereafter I guess the audio file should have an hidden characteristic, something like "finish time".

Did I miss some options in order to specify the maximum duration of the audio when I did an API call ? Or could I overwrite the end time by the "finish time" in php or at least being capable to to get this "finish time".

```
    $username = '****************';
    $password = '****************';
    $headers = array( 'Content-Type: application/json',
                      'Accept: audio/wav');

    $data_json = json_decode($input['text'], true); 
    $postdata = array(
        'accept'    => 'audio/wav',
        'text'      => $data_json['text']
    );
    $data_json = json_encode($postdata); 

    $curlPost = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=".$language); 
    curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
    curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json); 
    $response  = curl_exec($curlPost);
    curl_close($curlPost);

    $filePathName = './storage/' . uniqid() . '-Speaking.wav';
    if(!file_put_contents($filePathName, $response)){
        return response()->json(array(
                    'code' => '300',
                    'msg'  => 'Error creating file'
        ));
    }
```

Why I need to do so ? Because my colleague needs to read the audio file in C++.